# How to replace property value in dynamic JSON

Tags: c#, regex, json, replace, json.net

How to replace property value in JSON string?

I have json data as follows:

```
{
  "httpCode" : 200,
  "message" : "OK",
  "result" : {
    "furnitureItem" : {
      "id" : "f_1150426",
      "vertical" : "furniture",
      "title" : "Antique Tribal Gashgai Persian Rug",
      "description" : "Named after the Qashqa'i tribe in Persia, these nomadic rugs represent the skillful weaving styles of the tribe. Combining unique details with traditional family motifs the rugs are heavily ornamented. They often feature geometric patterns and highly developed floral designs. The colors often feature red, saffron yellow and navy. A distinguishable mark of Qashqai antique rugs is the use of flat weave.",
      "dealerReference" : "47550",
      "dibsReference" : "LU85971150426",
      "dateAdded" : "2014-05-12T15:23:26.000-04:00",
      "dateSold" : "1969-12-31T19:00:00.000-05:00",
      "releaseDate" : "2014-05-14T11:00:00.000-04:00",
      "modifiedDate" : "2014-05-12T23:48:19.000-04:00",
      "uploadType" : "USER",
      "status" : {
        "productStatus" : "UNRELEASED",
        "contactForPrice" : "N",
        "locked" : "Y",
        "posted" : "Y",
        "newListing" : "N",
        "inSaturdaySale" : "Y",
        "saveReleaseLater" : "N"
      },
      "overrideShipping" : "N",
      "pieces" : 1,
      "material" : {
        "description" : "Wool / hand Made",
        "restricted" : "N"
      },
      "customMaterial" : {
        "restricted" : "N",
        "description" : "Wool / hand Made"
      },
      "publishOptions" : {
        "dibs" : "Y",
        "featured" : "Y",
        "nydc" : "N",
        "storefront" : "Y",
        "workInProgress" : "N",
        "listedFrenchItem" : "N",
        "addText" : "N",
        "queuedForPosting" : "N",
        "rejected" : "N",
        "approved" : "N",
        "onHold" : "N",
        "deleted" : "N",
        "sold" : "N",
        "photoRepair" : "N",
        "previouslySold" : "N",
        "unpublished" : "N"
      },
      "seller" : {
        "id" : "f_8597",
        "status" : "active"
      },
      "store" : {
        "id" : 617
      },
      "classification" : {
        "style" : { },
        "countryOfOrigin" : "Iran",
        "categories" : [ "J32" ],
        "creationDate" : "Circa 1900",
        "period" : "_1900_TO_1920"
      },
      "measurement" : {
        "unit" : "IN",
        "width" : "60",
        "length" : "87",
        "weight" : { },
        "volume" : "0.0",
        "shape" : "rectangular2d"
      },
      "condition" : {
        "state" : "EXCELLENT",
        "damageLosses" : "N",
        "damageLight" : "N",
        "damageSound" : "N",
        "damageFading" : "N"
      },
      "images" : [ {
        "position" : 1,
        "status" : "PENDING",
        "thumb" : "/archivesE/upload/8597/20_14/antiquetribalgashgaipersianrug/antiquetribalGashgaipersianrug47550nazmiyal_t.jpeg",
        "small" : "/archivesE/upload/8597/20_14/antiquetribalgashgaipersianrug/antiquetribalGashgaipersianrug47550nazmiyal_l_s.jpeg",
        "medium" : "/archivesE/upload/8597/20_14/antiquetribalgashgaipersianrug/antiquetribalGashgaipersianrug47550nazmiyal_l_m.jpeg",
        "large" : "/archivesE/upload/8597/20_14/antiquetribalgashgaipersianrug/antiquetribalGashgaipersianrug47550nazmiyal_l.jpeg"
      }, {
        "position" : 2,
        "large" : ""
      }, {
        "position" : 3,
        "large" : ""
      }, {
        "position" : 4,
        "large" : ""
      }, {
        "position" : 5,
        "large" : ""
      }, {
        "position" : 6,
        "large" : ""
      }, {
        "position" : 7,
        "large" : ""
      }, {
        "position" : 8,
        "large" : ""
      }, {
        "position" : 9,
        "large" : ""
      }, {
        "position" : 10,
        "large" : ""
      } ],
      "shipping" : [ {
        "id" : 228066,
        "quoteSource" : {
          "role" : "SELLER",
          "id" : "f_8597"
        },
        "shipmentQuoteType" : "PRE_QUOTE",
        "currency" : "USD",
        "subTotal" : 0.00,
        "totalAmount" : 0.00,
        "shipmentCostIncluded" : "Y",
        "complimentaryShipping" : "Y",
        "handlingTimeDays" : 2,
        "serviceMethod" : {
          "windowMin" : 3,
          "windowMax" : 21,
          "windowUnit" : "DAY",
          "region" : "REST_OF_WORLD",
          "methodName" : "STANDARD"
        },
        "anchor" : {
          "sourceId" : "f_1150426",
          "sourceType" : "ITEM"
        },
        "amountCurrencies" : {
          "EUR" : 0.00,
          "PND" : 0.00,
          "USD" : 0.00
        },
        "invoiceItemType" : "SHIPMENT",
        "adjustmentDocumentType" : "SHIPMENT_QUOTE"
      } ],
      "pricing" : {
        "currency" : "USD",
        "lowestPrice" : 0.0,
        "amount" : 9500.0,
        "pricePerPiece" : "N",
        "negotiable" : "Y",
        "hidePrice" : "N",
        "bargain" : "N",
        "qualifyForBargain" : "Y",
        "initialPrice" : 9500,
        "initialPriceCurrencies" : {
          "EUR" : 6745.00,
          "PND" : 5510.00,
          "USD" : 9500.00
        },
        "amountCurrencies" : {
          "EUR" : 6745.00,
          "PND" : 5510.00,
          "USD" : 9500.00
        }
      },
      "returnPolicy" : { }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to replace the value of "images" property with following:

```
      "images": [
        {
          "position": 1,
          "thumb": "/archivesE/upload/8597/20_14/1150426/1150426_t.jpeg",
          "small": "/archivesE/upload/8597/20_14/1150426/1150426_l_s.jpeg",
          "medium": "/archivesE/upload/8597/20_14/1150426/1150426_l_m.jpeg",
          "large": "/archivesE/upload/8597/20_14/1150426/1150426_l.jpeg"
        },
        {
          "position": 2,
          "thumb": null,
          "small": null,
          "medium": null,
          "large": ""
        },
        {
          "position": 3,
          "thumb": null,
          "small": null,
          "medium": null,
          "large": ""
        },
        {
          "position": 4,
          "thumb": null,
          "small": null,
          "medium": null,
          "large": ""
        },
        {
          "position": 5,
          "thumb": null,
          "small": null,
          "medium": null,
          "large": ""
        },
        {
          "position": 6,
          "thumb": null,
          "small": null,
          "medium": null,
          "large": ""
        },
        {
          "position": 7,
          "thumb": null,
          "small": null,
          "medium": null,
          "large": ""
        },
        {
          "position": 8,
          "thumb": null,
          "small": null,
          "medium": null,
          "large": ""
        },
        {
          "position": 9,
          "thumb": null,
          "small": null,
          "medium": null,
          "large": ""
        },
        {
          "position": 10,
          "thumb": null,
          "small": null,
          "medium": null,
          "large": ""
        }
      ],
```

I tried RegEx:

```
"images"\s*:\s*\[\s*{[\s\S]+}
```

**UPDATE**
Here's what I have tried with JSON.NET:
I am not able to set the property value of the "images" array

```
void Main()
{
    var newValue = new[] { new Test(){Position="1"}, new Test(){Position="2"}};
    string json = File.ReadAllText("E:\\JSON.txt");
    dynamic rss = JObject.Parse(json);
    rss["result"]["furnitureItem"]["images"] = newValue;//this line throws error
    Console.WriteLine(rss.ToString());
}

public class Test
{
    public string Position {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest using some sort of JSON parser rather than a RegEx.

Comment: I cant use json parser as I don't know exactly how many properties are there in source JSON object... I am only sure that the object has "images" property

Comment: I want to leave the other properties as it is and just replace the "images" object with new value

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
JObject rss = JObject.Parse(json);
JObject furnitures = rss.SelectToken("result").SelectToken("furnitureItem");
furnitures ["images"] = newValue;
```

Comment: This requires Newtonsoft.Json and using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

Answer (score 2):

You can use Newtonsoft JToken to replace the value, it much easier as it support json path, below are the code snippet.

```
var parseResponse = JToken.Parse(jsonString);
var selectedPath = parseResponse.SelectToken("$.result.furnitureItem.images");
if(selectedPath!=null){
selectedPath.Replace(newValue);
}
```